# Css, position fixed doesn't work on mobile

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this site:
davdev.co.il/broker

in there I have a div with this rules:

```
.contact-mobile{
    position: fixed !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    max-width: 100vw;
    background-color: $black;
    opacity: 0.9;

    a{
        min-width: 25%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        i{
            color: #fff;
        }
        &:hover{
            opacity: 1;
            i{
                color: $black;
            }
            background-color: $green;

        }
    }
}
```

for some reason that I cant understand the div appears after scrolling and it is not always fixed to the bottom as it should be.

In the desktop, the position is fixed and works great.
The issue is only in the mobile.

this is an image of the div the one in the bottom with the red border
[image]

Comment: what's the mobile browser you see this error in? only Firefox 64 for android and Samsung Internet after v6.2 has full support for position: fixed.. see all [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20fixed)

Comment: Chrome, Dolphin, and desktop chrome on mobile view (ctrl+shift+m)

Comment: desktop chrome has partial support. Dolphin support, I dunno. anyway, you can check from the link given above

Comment: The fixed works good, the problem is that I have an unwanted horizontal scroll 
See this image. do you know How can I solve it? `overflow-x: hidden` didn't helped  https://www.screencast.com/t/P7zQwdWySBv

Comment: that means one of the elements have a css problem. try following. using inspector, try to remove a section one by one, while constantly checking horizontal scrollbar status. by this you can identify which causes the error.

Comment: also your site shows numerous errors in console. try to fix them first